# Test for specific number of words to match, with a known separator with Regex in Js

Tags: javascript, regex

i'm trying to check wether a string matches a set of values and they are seperated by a ; It needs to have ; as a separator.
I go this `new RegExp(/\b(Segunda|Terça|Quarta|Quinta|Sexta|Sábado|Domingo)\b/, 'gi').test(str)`

If i pass:

- 'Segunda;Terça', true.
- 'Segundaaa', false.
- 'Segunda;Terçaa', true.. Why is it true? how can i avoid this?

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT] code:

```
const WEEK_DAYS_GROUP_REGEX = /\b(Segunda|Terça|Quarta|Quinta|Sexta|Sábado|Domingo)\b/;

const res = new RegExp(WEEK_DAYS_GROUP_REGEX, 'i').test('Segunda;Terçaa');

console.log(res) // gives true
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew that does not solve it

Comment: Show me the code. Do you mean you want to match a `;`-separated string of some specific names only? See [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/wayt6C/1).

Comment: yes, i just want to match those possibilites of values, the ; separator would be helpfull, but optional, as in, it doens't have to be ;, it can be other stuff

Comment: no, it needs something separating it, yes

Comment: what more details would be useful?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170251/discussion-between-franmcod-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Comment: the demo you showed works, i didnt see before you had put that there, sorry. make that the answer and ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/\b(Segunda|Terça|Quarta|Quinta|Sexta|Sábado|Domingo)\b/` pattern with `gi` modifiers matches any of the alternatives as a whole word, it does not guarantee that the whole string consists of these values only, let alone the `;` delimiter.

You  may use

```
^(<ALTERNATIONS>)(?:;(<ALTERNATIONS>))*$
```

See the [pattern demo](https://regex101.com/r/wayt6C/1).

In JS, you do not need to use that long pattern, you may build the pattern dynamically:

```js
const strs = ["Segunda;Terça", "Segundaaa", "Segunda;Terçaa"];
const vals = "Segunda|Terça|Quarta|Quinta|Sexta|Sábado|Domingo";
let rx = new RegExp("^(?:" + vals + ")(?:;(?:" + vals + "))*$", "i");
console.log(rx);
for (let s of strs) {
  console.log(s,"=>",rx.test(s));
}
```

Note that the non-capturing groups `(?:...)` are preferred when there is no need extracting submatches, group values.

Comment: I'm curious as to why non-capturing groups are preferred?

Comment: @Nick Because there is no redundant memory allocation for submatches.